# What is the missing value in this number pyramid?

Tags: mathematics, visual

The following question was asked in a mock test for which I am preparing and I was unable to solve it.

[image]

What is the missing number? It must be one of these answers:

A -19
B -5
C 9
D -9

The pattern I saw was that each block is the sum of the two directly below it, divided by two. For example, 5 (the top number) = (8 + 2) / 2. Using this pattern I got -1 as the answer but it's not an option and I am unable to see any other pattern.

So, can someone please tell me how should I attempt the question?

Comment: Perhaps you mistakenly used +5 instead of -5 in the last block of the third row, when calculating your provisional answer of -1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer should be

> A -19

Because

> If you add two adjacent blocks and divide by 2 you get the number of the block on top of/above them

> F ex. 8+2=10 ----> 10/2=5

Comment: Looks like we both spotted this within moments of each other!

Comment: we did, but I think you're right with the "trick"

Answer (score 12):

If the dividing line between the '9' and '?' cells is actually supposed to be positioned more to the right, then the answer is:

> **A) -19**

Because:

> The number above each pair of two adjacent cells is their **arithmetical average** (i.e. the mean) - e.g. for the top two rows, 5 is the average of 8 and 2.
>
>  In this case, the average of 9 and -19 yields -5 (the cell above them), as required.

However, if this is intended as a trick question and the solver is supposed to note that the -5 cell is *only* above a single box, then:

> that box should contain the answer **B) -5**, as the average of one value is that value itself...!

It really depends on whether that line is positioned correctly or if it is intended as a trick question.

Comment: nice, deja vu :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is...

> A(-19)

Because...

> I made a drawing so that it is clearer:
>  [image]
>  The three blocks(like in the drawing) that contain the block with the question mark is outlined in red:
>  [image]
>  In this case, $a=-5$, $b=9$, and $c$ is the one represented with the question mark.
>  Therefore, $c=2a-b=-10-9=-19$. Hence, the answer is -19(option A)